# Can't run or debug SVN android project

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, subversive, motodev-studio

I'm having some beginner problems to start using version control on my project. My app is already working, I've installed subversive and did the following:
1- Checked out my project to server - OK.
2- At another pc, added new repository location - OK.

I can see the project tree in SVN Repositories perspective, with all files, but when I try to run it, what appears in the emulator is the local version of the project, and not the SVN one.

I've tried Run > Run Configurations > New Launch Configurations, but the SVN repository doesn't appears in Basic settings > Browse Project...

In repository I can see, but not edit, .classpath and .project files.

Any idea of what's happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be downloading your project from SVN into a folder somewhere on your PC.  You need to add that project to Eclipse, or refresh if you downloaded it to an existing project folder, and then rebuild the project in Eclipse.

Comment: I did File > New > Project..., then Project from SVN > Use existing repository location (https://netserver.aglagla.local:8888/svn/android) > Select Resource (.../svn/android/myproject), Head Revision... Finally, Check out as a project with the name specified: myproject, Depth Recursively, etc  etc... Now, when I try to run, it displays "Launching Job - Performing pre-launch check" at Progress tab and staus at 7% indefinitely (I guess it happens because I've renamed my old local project folder, before checking out).

Comment: I would just do it with the command line.  Download your project somewhere and then have Eclipse handle it.  Going through Eclipse's GUI import method might be finicky.